# Data Modeling: how to "normalize" same items identified to be different?

Tags: database, data-modeling, database-design

Say I have as my input inventory of store items coming from different merchants. Further, say that some of these items may be the same between different merchants (e.g. 2 merchants sell Xboxes, but have different fields, ids, etc to describe the item). How do I model a database such that I know that my inventory item 1 is the same as Merchant 1's inventory item 255 is the same as Merchant 2's inventory item 45 is the same as ....?

I want my users to be able to indicate they are interested in my item 1 -- and I need to know how this translate to how the various merchants identify the same product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need and item_x_merchant table.

With columns my_id, merchant_id, merchants_item_id.

Comment: With those columns (which I agree), the table should be **item_merchant**.

Comment: Naming conventions vary from site to site. I was taught to always stick the _X_ in the name of an intersection table and continue to do so as it makes perfect sense.

Comment: 1. It is possible some sites may not be able to read Data Models and need funny things in the table names, but that is hardly good advice for people who can read. 2. This is not an "intersection" table if you mean an Associative table (that resolves the many-to-many logical relation), which is the FKs only; it contains data, as per your identified `merchants_item_id` column.